# IMPORTRANGE from a separate sheet based on closest date to today's date

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query, google-sheets-arrayformula, importrange, google-sheets-dates

Sheet1 will have data with different past dates

Sheet2 - I want to import data from the 1st sheet and find the closest date to today's date.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Kr5NRb4TmNhr8hQb2DXt6pdK4UC3H1IUFGjvQtucWQw/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: pls share a copy of your sheet

Comment: Please add a brief description of your search/research efforts as is suggested on [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you want to get data in the same spreadsheet you do not need **`IMPORTRANGE`**.
 Let's say **Sheet1** looks like this:

[image: 0]

Then in **Sheet2** you need to do this:

```
=FILTER(Sheet1!A:Z, Sheet1!A:A=MAX(Sheet1!A:A), Sheet1!A:A<=TODAY())
```

[image: 0]